# favorite button: pass cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, button

help please!
I am spending a lot of time to create a favorite button and i stack :\,
I have a table view cell and I would like to create a button that when I press the button the cell will appear at the favorite tab.
I started to create that button and now it changes color when I press it and it is stored with `NSUserDefault`
. The last thing i need is to pass the cell into my favorite tab.

Here is my code:

import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import MapKit

```
class BarProfileTableViewController: UITableViewController,MKMapViewDelegate{


    let Favoritebutton: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)


    Favoritebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "EmptyHeart.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    Favoritebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "FilledHeart.png"), forState: UIControlState.Selected)

    Favoritebutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.button(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

 var favorites : [String] = [""]

    Favoritebutton.frame = CGRectMake(90, 90, 35, 35)

     //create a new button
        let Favoritebutton: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
        //set image for button
        Favoritebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "EmptyHeart.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        Favoritebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "FilledHeart.png"), forState: UIControlState.Selected)
        //add function for button
        Favoritebutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.button(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        //set frame
        Favoritebutton.frame = CGRectMake(90, 90, 35, 35)

        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: Favoritebutton)
        //assign button to navigationbar
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton

        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        let buttonIsSelected = defaults.boolForKey("keyForIsButtonSelected") // If no value exists for this key then false is returned

        Favoritebutton.selected = buttonIsSelected

            }
```

**my Favorites View Controller:**

```
  import UIKit
class FavoritesViewController : UITableViewController {
```

[image: example 1]
[image: after you press]

here is an example:

Comment: Question is not clear can you share some screen what you mean "cell will appear at the favorite tab" ?

Comment: now when you click on favorite button you want to update tab bar item badge ?

Comment: sorry nope! you have to share some codes to understand what you mean to passing cell?

Comment: i will be more specifically i have a table view cell and i have a favorite button i want that when you press the button the cell will appear at the favorite tab in every app with favorite buttons @MücahitTekin

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying what I think you are saying, I am assuming the 'favorite tab' as you call it, is a section of your app that contains a `UITableView` of all the users favorite songs and your goal is to move a song that the user decides to favorite to the `favoritesTableView`, I am going to call it, then you should do the following.

Inside the `Favoritebutton` action:

```
func favoriteSong (_ sender:UIButton) {

  /* Right here you are going to want to insert the song data that is in the current tableViewCell which the user wishes to add to favorites */

  // I am assuming that your data of all your songs is stored in some sort of array

  // You will have to get the song title, artist, ect data from your cell which you can use something like this to access

  let p: CGPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: songTableView)
  var indexPath: IndexPath = songTableView.indexPathForRow(at: p)!
  let cell = songTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!

  // These are made up arrays that I assume you have something along the lines of in your app and for the purpose of this answer we are going to assume that the song title is your UITableViewCell's 'textLabel' and your song artist is your UITableViewCell's 'detailTextLabel'


  favoritesSongTitleArray.append(cell.textLabel!)
  favoritesSongArtistArray.append(cell.detailTextLabel!)

  // Then I am going to assume (alot of assumptions here :/ ) your 'favoritesTableView' gets its data from these arrays and therefor all you have to do is reload the favoritesTableView like this  

  favoritesTableView.reloadData()

}
```

You should have something like this then inside your UITableViewController for delegate methods

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  // Put whatever format you wish for the cell here
  let cell =  UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

  cell.textLabel.text = favoritesSongTitleArray[indexPath.row]
  cell.detailTextLabel.text = favoritesSongArtistArray[indexPath.row]

  return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  return favoritesSongTitleArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

  return 50
}
```

The cell the user favorited should then appear in your `favoritesTableView`. I hope this helps.

PS: From the code I see, it looks like you also need to call `defaults.synchronize()` to actually save the favorite

Comment: hey, first thanks, can you match your answer to my code please?@garret kaye

Comment: I would gladly do so but you need to provide more code, but is answer along the lines of what you were looking for?

Comment: Well, I want to help you but I am not going to write your code for you. If you don't have a method handler for when the user favorites a song, I suggest you make one like the one I provided in the answer. You will then have to add that favorite button to each tableViewCell. Im sorry I just don't have a lot to go off here you are going to have to figure out some stuff on your own. It seems like you have a lot of questions I would recommend you read up on UITableViews.

Comment: I just need that to pass the cell I just started coding and I stack in this button months :\

Comment: See my updated answer, you can NOT just pass a cell to another UITableView and simply add it to the tableView. You need to recreate it. By updating the arrays that your FavoritesViewController uses to generate the cells in its UITableView and calling `reloadData()` on your tableViewController it will add your desired cell.

Comment: hey thanks can you write tho code in swift 2.3 please?

Comment: Just get rid of the underscore `_ ` in the parameter clause for each function and instead of  `IndexPath` change it to `NSIndexPath` also `CGPoint.zero` should be `CGPointZero` and you should be good to go for swift 2.3. If my answer helped you, would you mind giving it the green checkmark? :)

Comment: Sure if its work I will very happy to give you the check mark

Comment: what i need to put instead of the songTableView

Comment: can you match it to my code please? I got 5 errors please help